# How to check two conditions inside rendered attribute?

Tags: jsf, el, multiple-conditions, rendered-attribute

I tried below code

```
   <h:form rendered="{#{cars.enabled} and #{cars.enabledEdit}}">
```

But this doesn't works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a proper EL Expression

```
<h:form rendered="#{cars.enabled and cars.enabledEdit}">
```

No need (and its even illegal to use #{} inside #{})

Comment: Probably should mention that chances are ajax-updating that form would fail, if that's OP's ultimate goal